# Sum all records from each do loop?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database

Let's say the I have a retreat. And that retreat has 2 different teams that are part of that retreat.

Team a has 3 users

Team b has 1 user

In the block of code below, I will see an output that displays two different rows. One row that has the number 3 and another with the number 1.

```
<% @retreat.teams.each do |team| %>
  <p>Attending: <%= link_to(team.name, team_path(team.id)) %></p>
  <%= team.users.distinct.count :user_id %>
<% end %>
```

How do I combine all records so the output is 4? Or the sum of all unique users of each team that is part of a retreat?

Comment: Hint: `count = 0` and in the loop `<% count += team.users.distinct.count :user_id %>`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Model:

```
# app/models/retreat.rb

has_many :users, through: :teams
```

View:

```
# app/views/retreat/show.html.erb

<%= @retreat.users.distinct.count %>
```

Comment: Ugh. I tried this earlier but forgot to restart my server (it's getting late). Thank you!